# Unable to fix incompatible versions when unpickling a model trained in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, joblib

I have a RandomForestClassifier model to detect bots trained in Google Colab, it works well in that environment and the predictions are quite accurate, but when I save it using `joblib`, and use it in my own python venv using the same libraries' version, always get this message:

```
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 0.24 when using version 1.2.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use it at your own risk.
```

And the prediction is quite different than the Colab's, wrong actually.
I tried downgrading my scikit-learn version to 0.24, but again I get this message:

```
UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestClassifier from version 1.2.2 when using version 0.24. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use it at your own risk.
```

This is how I fit and save my model using `Pipeline`:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('preprocessing', StandardScaler()), ('classifier', grid.best_estimator)])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(pipeline, '/content/drive/MyDrive/modelV4.pkl', compress = 1)
```

I don't know what to do, according to `pip freeze > requirements.txt` command, Colab has `scikit-learn==1.2.2` just as my python venv, why do I get this warning? How can I fix it? And is this the cause of my wrong predictions against Colab's? Hope you can help me.

I tried downgrading and updating libraries' version in Colab and my venv but nothing works. The warning's still there and the predictions are wrong.